# Index Path nested Tableview in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `tableview` which is inside a tableview cell. I need the main tableview index path in that sub tableview "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method . I am stuck on this point. My datasource and delegate methods are in same class.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Configure the cell...
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil && [tableView tag] == 200) {
    //main tableview
 }
else if(cell == nil && tableView.tag == 106)
{
  //sub tableview
   here I need the index path of main tableview
} 

}
```

How can I get the index path of main table view?
[image]

Comment: You are trying to get a drop down cell?

Comment: @lakesh no.. its another tableview

Comment: How is your structure of cell ? Table 1->cell1->table2->cell2 or the second table is embeded in  a view and added to outer table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) tableView.superview.superview.superview;
UITableView *curTableView = (UITableView *)cell.superview;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [curTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Comment: UITableViewCell *cell1 = (UITableViewCell *) tableView.superview.superview.superview;
By dis I solved my problem..
Thq gyes